# Cannot read property 'domain' of undefined in error handler in express 4

Tags: node.js, express

I am configuring a sample app in express.I am using express 4 and my node version 0.10.33. I have installed error-handler module  and on running the app i got the following error

```
 domain.js:88
 if (ee.domain === this) return;
    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'domain' of undefined
at Domain.add (domain.js:88:9)
```

This is my code

app.js

```
   var express = require('express'),
   bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
   methodOverride = require('method-override'),
   errorHandler = require('error-handler'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
   api = require('./routes/api'),
  http = require('http'),
  path = require('path');

   var app = module.exports = express();

 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
 app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
 }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(methodOverride());
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

 // development only
 if (env === 'development') {
  app.use(errorHandler());
 }

// production only
if (env === 'production') {
// TODO
}

// redirect all others to the index (HTML5 history)
app.get('*', routes.index);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
 console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Can anybody help me out to solve these issue

Comment: please provide full stack trace

Comment: `error-handler` doesn't provide a valid Express/Connect middleware, you can't `app.use(...)` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try unistalling the npm module with : npm uninstall error-handler --save....
and then intall the package errohandler: npm install errorhandler. that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

app.use(errorHandler) instead of app.use(errorHandler());